# Error Handler in Multiple Projects in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, jar, microservices

I'm currently working with different services divided in different projects in Spring Boot.

I have made an error handler which will be a JAR for all the projects, so when I have

`com.my.package` in all the projects the error handler works fine.

```
com.my.package.Controller
com.my.package.Entity
...
```

My Exception Response:

```
    "code": 400,
    "message": "'id' must be java.lang.Integer",
    "status": "BAD_REQUEST"
}
```

But the problem is when I have

`com.my.package.p1` -> for project p1

`com.my.package.p2` -> for project p2

```
com.my.package.p1.Controller
com.my.package.p1.Entity
...
```

```
com.my.package.p2.Controller
com.my.package.p2.Entity
...
```

the error handler seems to fail in its job and the default handler resolves the error, rather than mine.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-09-30T23:58:57.379+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"j\"",
    "path": "/api/department/j"
}
```

These are my classes from my JAR

```
//@RestControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.my.package")
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

      //405
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
    protected GlobalException processMethodNotSupportedException(final HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Method not allowed");  
        return new GlobalException(405, "Method not allowed",HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
    }

...
```

As you see, I tried using @RestControllerAdvice and @ControllerAdvice, and trying to use annotation *basePackages* but there was not succesful result.

I also made another class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.my.package")
@EntityScan("com.my.package")
public class SharedBeanReference {

}
```

But same result.

Can somebody help me figuring out what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying the basepackage of the controller advice using the annotation like :

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.my.package")
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

      //405
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
    protected GlobalException processMethodNotSupportedException(final HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Method not allowed");  
        return new GlobalException(405, "Method not allowed",HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
    }

...
```

> For @ExceptionHandler methods, a root exception match will be
>   preferred to just matching a cause of the current exception, among the
>   handler methods of a particular advice bean. However, a cause match on
>   a higher-priority advice will still be preferred over any match
>   (whether root or cause level) on a lower-priority advice bean. As a
>   consequence, please declare your primary root exception mappings on a
>   prioritized advice bean with a corresponding order.

Or you could try the following :

- Try providing the controller advice class a higher priority or order using the `@Priority` or `@Order` annotation so that it gets matched.
- You need make sure that the `@ControllerAdvice` Class is under your component-scan base package.

Reference [doc](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)
Official [Doc](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I've already had my file with `@ControllerAdvice` in the base package, I added the `basePackage=com.my.package` to the annotation but I still have same result. I also added `@Priority`, but no change.  I tried changing in the project the Application File to the base Package (from `com.my.package.p1' to `com.my.package' and it makes works fine. But I don't really want this.

Comment: Try adding all the related packages in the @ControllerAdvice annotation. Like @ControllerAdvice(basepackages={......p1,...p2..})